# PHP - Not replacing Õs

Tags: php, character-encoding, str-replace

So today I was updating some code I made that took some data from a webpage and emailed it to people for convenience. However, I noticed that whoever was typing the text used a program which used some other encoding which had a weird `’` character which was `0xD5` (213) in the Mac Roman set. But when they uploaded it to their website, it came out as `Õ`. So I used php and did this:

```
$parsed = str_ireplace("Õ", "'", $parsed);
```

So I did this and tested it, but it didn't seem to work. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: str_ireplace — Case-insensitive version of str_replace(). @LuthandoLoot. so it is not a spelling mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is just a single anomaly you're correcting you can specify it with a hex escape sequence like:

```
$parsed = str_replace("\xD5", "'", $parsed);
```

The reason just `"Õ"` isn't working is the encoding of your PHP file doesn't represent Õ as 0xD5. Strings are just byte sequences and what you're giving `str_ireplace` don't match. (Well, that and `str_ireplace` is gonna do funky things with it, `str_replace` is preferred here.)

---

More appropriate to handle the problem in general would be to use [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) to convert the input string from whatever its source encoding is into the output encoding you need.

Examples:

```
$parsed = iconv('MACINTOSH', 'UTF-8', $parsed);
```

or

```
$parsed = iconv('MACINTOSH', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $parsed);
```

The `//TRANSLIT` here means that when a character can't be represented in the target charset, it'll be approximated through one or several similarly looking characters. There's a lot ASCII (and others) can't represent, so transliteration can come in handy if you're not outputting UTF-8 (which would be ideal.)